# Transfer helpers and utilities from one app to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Recently I have been wandering in the Rails world (and enjoyed it so much).

I have finished my first project in Rails, and I have created a bunch of helpers to work with dates, menus and etc.

My question is, what is the best way to transfer these helpers (and some other files) from one project to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a gem. Start from [here](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/1/) for example.